# Stop MouseEvent-propagation of displayList views to starling views

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, starling-framework, displaylist

I'm creating a game that uses the starling-layer (the game itself) and the classic display list which contains several Popups and Stuff like that.

I have one thing that troubles me:
If MouseEvents are generated on displayList-elements they always go through to the starling layer and produce TouchEvents etc. which is quite annoying.

I was wondering there is some general (and easy to use) approach to handle that.

One possibility was to listen on all displayList-Elements for the following Events:

```
interfaceElement.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stopPropagationHandler);
interfaceElement.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stopPropagationHandler);
interfaceElement.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPropagationHandler);

private function stopPropagationHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

But this looks quite nasty to me. 
And even if I did it like that, I have one more issue:
If a starling-element is below that display-list-element and if it has a TouchEvent.TOUCH for rollover-behavior >> the rollover-appearance will not be removed from the starling if you hover over the display-list-element.

I also thought about putting a dummy-starling element behind every display-list-element,... to stop the events.. but that all sounds a bit "over-complicated" for such a "simple" task.
Or am I missing something?

A hint would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'd say use a globally available flag instead of event propagation block, that will be set if a modal popup is in play, so that each event handler on starling level will first check if it's set, and return if it is, so that Starling part of your SWF will behave as if nothing happens while there's a popup.

Comment: @Vesper thanks .. but as you already mentioned this would only work for modals. :/
I additionally have e.g. a chat that could be always visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create 1 main container in the displaylist (not the stage) and listen for ROLL_OVER and ROLL_OUT, and set somekind of global flag there, that your mouse is over the display-list container. Then in your starling events, check for this flag. This isn't the nicest solution out there i guess, but it should work

```
var isOverDisplayList:Boolean = false;
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onRollOver);
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onRollOut);

function onRollOver(e:MouseEvent) {
  isOverDisplayList = true;
}

function onRollOut(e:MouseEvent) {
  isOverDisplayList = false;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea.. at least I would get rid of the MOUSE_MOVE-listener which annoyed me most.
So it does not seem like their is some "buil-in" behavior which I missed.. a pity.

Comment: i notice i have 2 ROLL_OVER events there. Changed it to correct events

Comment: I implemented it now via the Rolling Events >> but instead of setting a variable I toggle the visibility of a Starling-Blocker which is on top of all Starling-Views. Thanks!